# Will transaction fail if a document in a sub-collection is modified?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Let's consider the following example:

```js
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

const userCollectionRef = firestore().collection('users');

const setUserData = (userId, data) => {
  return firestore().runTransaction(async trx => {
    const userDocRef = userCollectionRef.doc(userId);
    return trx.set(userDocRef, data);
  });
};

const doSomethingElse = (userId, doc, data) => {
  return userCollectionRef
    .doc(userId)
    .collection('subCollection')
    .doc(doc)
    .set(data);
};
```

If I call `setUserData(123, someData);` and while this function is in progress the `doSomethingElse(123, 'someDoc', someOtherData)` function gets called - will the transaction fail because a document in a sub-collection got modified?

Based on the docs I would assume that transaction will fail **only** if the `user/123` document is modified while `setUserData` call is in progress, but modifications to `user/123/subCollection/someDoc` document won't cause the transaction to fail. I'm not sure though because [the transaction failure docs section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) is not very explicit about it. It just says:

> The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

Comment: While I don't "know" the answer, I can say that documents and documents in their sub-collections are entirely separate - in your example of user/123/subCollection/someDoc, the document 123 is *only* used as part of the path/index to "someDoc" - there is no other relation between them.  In fact, document user/123 could be REMOVED and the path to user/123/subCollection/someDoc would remain valid (it shows in Firebase console as an italicized path)

Answer (score 2):

While I don't "know" the answer, I can say that documents and documents in their sub-collections are entirely separate - in your example of `user/123/subCollection/someDoc`, the document `user/123` is *only* used as part of the path/index to `user/123/subCollection/someDoc` - there is no other relation between them.  In fact, document `user/123` could be REMOVED and the path to `user/123/subCollection/someDoc` would remain valid (it shows in Firebase console as an italicized path)